# What part of my xslt is causing the process to take hours?

Tags: xml, performance, xslt

The following XSLT takes hours to run. Most XSLT that I run takes seconds or minutes.  What am I doing wrong?  The goal is to take Word XHTML and convert it to a flat file to import into a dictionary program called FLEx.  This is just one step in identifying the pieces of the dictionary. I have an input XHTML file of 52K. I do the conversion in 27 steps. The initial ones are done using Saxon and XSLT.  The final steps are done with a special program called CC which predates AWK and Pearl. It is a string replacement tool that is very efficient. It takes seconds to process the files in CC. The first 8 steps are XSLT and take forever (more than 3 hours) to run each step.
The last XSLT flattens the file so it is no longer in XML. CC works on the text file.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY cr "&#xD;&#xA;">
<!ENTITY tab "&#9;">
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;">
]><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="3.0">
    
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="html:span[@class='source']" priority='4'>
       <xsl:element name="span">
           <xsl:attribute name="class">source</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="html">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="html:i" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 italic</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="html:b">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(.,'Derivation')">
         <xsl:element name="span">
             <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3dd derivation</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>           
            <xsl:when test="ancestor::*[contains(@class,'1.4 lx')]">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>           
            <xsl:when test="ends-with(.,'-')">
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3a variant-none</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="preceding::*[1]=preceding::html:br[1] and not(contains(.,'Forms')) and not(starts-with(following::text()[1],'(')[1])">
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 variant-space</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
                    <!--          <xsl:value-of select="."/> joins that we don't want-->     
                </xsl:element></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="preceding::*[1]=preceding::html:br[1] and not(contains(.,'Forms'))" >
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 variant-none</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>     
                </xsl:element></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
           </xsl:otherwise>         
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="html:br">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(following::text()[1],' (')">
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 text-(</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>      
          </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following::*[1]=following::html:span[@class='MsoHyperlink'][following::*[1]=following::html:b[1]]">
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>               
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following::*[1]=following::html:span[@class='MsoHyperlink']">
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>               
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following::*[1]=following::html:span[@class='Arial'][1]">
                <!--      2.3 -->  
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(following::text()[1],'variant of')">
                <!--      2.3 variant of-->  
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following::*[1]=following::html[b][1] and contains(following::html:b[1],'Forms')">
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="preceding::text()[1]=')'">
                <!--      2.3 -->  
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>               
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3b definition</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:call-template name="processBold"/> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(following::text()[1],'(')">
                <!--      2.3 -->  
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>               
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 gid</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:call-template name="processBold"/> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(following::text()[1],'(')">
                <!--      2.3 -->  
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>               
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 gid</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:call-template name="processBold"/> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--      2.3 -->  
                <xsl:call-template name="makeLineBreak"/>               
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3 definition</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:call-template name="processBold"/> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="processBold">
            <xsl:choose> 
                <xsl:when test="self::html:b and preceding::*[1]=preceding::span[1][@class='vernacular']">
                    2.3 vernacular bold 
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text> 
                </xsl:when> 
                <xsl:when test="self::html:b">
                    2.3 bold 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/> 
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text> 
                </xsl:when> 
                <xsl:when test="self::html:span[@class='Arial']"> 
                    <xsl:element name="span">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3a definition</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>          
                </xsl:when> 
                
                <xsl:otherwise> 
                </xsl:otherwise> 
            </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="html:span[@lang][parent::html:b]" priority="1">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="preceding::*[1]=preceding::html:br[1]">
              <xsl:element name="span">
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">2.3va variant-none</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test=".='/'">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="contains(.,'-')">
              <xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:otherwise>      
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="makeLineBreak">
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>      
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- identify transform -->  
    <xsl:template match="@*|*|processing-instruction()|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why would you think it's reasonable to ask a performance question without providing (a) any measurement data / profiling results at all, (b) any input data, and (c) only one of eight steps in your process?

Comment: Expressions like `preceding::*[1]=preceding::html:br[1]` look odd and expensive. What are you trying to achieve there, isn't any HTML `br` element always empty? Are you perhaps looking for node identity `is` instead of `=`? And as you have various such checks or similar checks, can you explain the transformation you need to achieve? Perhaps using grouping with `group-starting-with` is an option. It also helps if you tell us exactly which version of Saxon you use. Have you tried other XSLT processors, as it seems there is nothing Saxon specific or XSLT 3 specific in the code?

Comment: If you would structure your question, it would be easier to grasp, what you are asking. As I understand it, the first sentence is the one with the question, and that you are applying Saxon (you missed the version). I cannot find helpful information in the rest.<BR/>What I spotted: your use of namespace looks odd to me: two different xmlns for the same namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few expressions like

```
test="following::*[1]=following::html:span[@class='MsoHyperlink'][following::*[1]=following::html:b[1]]">
```

In principle, evaluating the `following` (or `preceding`) axis takes time proportional to the size of the document. However, if it's followed by the predicate `[1]` then the search stops on hitting the first following node, which makes it run in constant time (i.e. time independent of document size). Three of your calls to `following` in this expression fall under that rule; the fourth (`following::html:span[@class='MsoHyperlink']`) does not. So this particular test is going to take time proportional to document size. You're evaluating this test once for every `br` element, so the number of times you evaluate it is presumably proportional to document size; this makes the overall cost O(n^2).

Very often, people use `preceding` and `following` where `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` would be more appropriate. I've no idea if that's the case here.

I suspect that in most of these expressions you are using "=" where you should be using "is". An "=" test on an element with a large subtree is very expensive (at least proportional to the size of the tree being compared).

You could start by staring at the code looking for obvious inefficiencies like these, or you could start with performance measurement and analysis of the results. When faced with large amounts of code, especially if it's unfamiliar code, the second approach is usually more productive. Start by getting the `-TP:profile.html` output to see if it identifies obvious hot-spots. Also, of course, get the timings for each of your 27 steps and decide which of them to focus on.

Comment: Michael, thank you for looking at the problem. I will surely try your suggestions. I could not find -TP documented.  Did you mean: MONITOR_­HOT_­SPOT_­BYTE_­CODE

-TB?

Comment: -TP is an option on the command line interface. There's no explicit equivalent in the Java API - the effect of this option is to set a TraceListener (specifically, the TimingTraceListener) on the transformation, and then when the transformation is finished, to do some analysis of the numbers and output an HTML report.

Comment: Run time is cut in half so far. I found one more place that needed [1] added so am running it again.  Where can I find more info on "is" vs "="?

Comment: "Where can I find more info on "is" vs "="?" - try my book, XSLT Programmers' Reference ;-)

Comment: I have 2nd edition book but don't see how to find /is/.  Do you have a page number?

Comment: I think the second edition only covered XSLT 1.0, whereas the "is" operator first appeared in XPath 2.0.

Comment: In the 4th edition, the `is` operator is covered on p593, and the dangers of using "=" to compare node identity are discussed on p591.

Comment: No wonder I didn't know about it.  Thanks again. XSLT 2.0 handles all my needs. Love Saxon!  Thanks for all your work!!!!  I know when you answer that that IS the answer. :)